# PostgreSQL query to find data between a date range

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to find the data in a table which has a date as a column. I need to find out the rows corresponding to the certain date range. How can I do this?

Comment: `where date_column between date '2017-09-01' and date '2017-09-11'`

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name I ignored the "date"  portion and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
SELECT * FROM <database_table> WHERE <date_field> BETWEEN "<start date>" AND "<end date>";
```